# Sat solvers with backdoor set

Tags: satisfiability, sat-solvers

I have large cnf with thousands of variables, but with known compact [backdoor set](https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/%7Etw/kstwaaai05.pdf).
I think this set can be used by CDCL solvers to choose assignment variables to simplify formula much faster, but I failed to find solver with such feature.

Kissat and cadical (top performers of [SAT competitions](http://www.satcompetition.org/)) can't do that.

Is there any solvers which can use backdoor set for speed up?

Edit: as a backdoor set I mean subset of variables that make formula solvable in polynomial time after assignment. For example if cnf with $N$ variables have backdoor set with $M<N$ variables then it solvation can be accelerated from $O(const_1^N)$ to $O(const_2^M) + O((N-M)^{const_3})$

Comment: I encourage you to [edit] your post to provide a self-contained definition of what you mean by a "backdoor".  (The paper isn't entirely clear to me, and it lists two separate definitions.)  You might have to implement your own algorithm to use this, so I think it's better to ask how to make use of this.  I'm not sure a question asking for an existing software package that happens to have this unusual feature will be on-topic here.

Comment: Please don't use "Edit: [more stuff added]".  Instead, revise your question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  It's often a good idea to define any technical terms before first use.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755

Comment: Also you definition isn't clear to me.  I don't know what you mean by "subset that make .. after assignment".  Do you mean that for every possible assignment, after (doing something with that assignment -- what? substituting into the formula?) the formula is solvable in polynomial time?  Something else?  I don't understand what you mean by "solvable in formula time".  For that to be meaningful, you have to specify a particular algorithm for solving it in polynomial time.  This issue is even mentioned in the paper.  Please specify what algorithm you have in mind.